# Using Wacom Tablet with Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, tablet

Is it possible to use a Wacom tablet with mapinfo ?

How accurate is it ?

I have a high end machine with dual monitors and I want to digitise field mapping (lots of small polys) quickly.

Comment: Which one? Wacom makes a few from very basic to high sensitivity. One of our operators uses a Wacom Bamboo tablet to capture and finds it faster (but no more accurate) than a mouse. Wacom also makes a pen/monitor combo that is said to be excellent (as seen on American Chopper) for CAD.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the Intuos pen/touch..... or the pro (medium size but the active area is quite small compared with the Intuos)...budget was around 3-450.

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo Pro does support tablets.

I must admit that it has been ages since I used one the last time. At that time I think we were using a third party Tablet Interface (Virtual Tablet Interface).

But I think today you can just use the Wintab interface.